# postgres sql , how to increment when null exists

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL, I would like to increment a field but it is `null` sometimes. 
How do I increment that field in `1` if it is not `null` and set it to `1` if it is `null`?

```
insert into table (id, inc) values('a',1) on conflict(id) do update set inc=inc;
```

When `id` already exists and `inc` is `null` it won't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10):

You can accomplish that with the help of the `coalesce` function:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id,inc) VALUES ('a',1)
ON CONFLICT (id)
DO UPDATE SET inc = coalesce(mytable.inc,0) + 1;
```

The key point is the expression `coalesce(mytable.inc,0)`, which means the following: if `mytable.inc` is not `NULL` then use that value, otherwise use the value `0`.