# PostgreSQL update doesn't work

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I am working on a PostgreSQL 9.5.3 db which I haven't setup myself. The issue that I have is that a simple update of the form: `UPDATE <table> SET <col> = <val> WHERE <col> = <old_val>;` does not apply the change. I mention that the pgAdmin output is:

> UPDATE 1
>
> Query returned successfully in .. msec

What could be the cause? Could it be explained by some set constraints?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any table partitioning  ?

Comment: `UPDATE 1` means that one row was updated - clearly your statement worked.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name When I do a SELECT afterwards, the value stayed the same.

Comment: Missing a `commit` maybe?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name "Auto commit" is set in pgAdmin

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla Do you know if/how I can check this in pgAdmin 4?

Comment: \d+ <table_name> to check if the table has partitions. Remove angle brackets.

Comment: Without more information this is impossible to answer. Could be you are connected to a different database when you check the update or you have a trigger that reverts the assignment of the value or some other process/transaction reverted your change. But if Postgres returns that one row update, then one row _was_ updated.

Comment: do you have triggers AFTER update on the table?..

Comment: @VaoTsun This was it! I found the update trigger that matched on the record in question. Thank you all for the guidance!

Comment: please share the definition of update function, so I could answer and other users could learn from our experience

Comment: @VaoTsun It was a trigger on update that blocked updates if some other column had a pre-defined value.

Comment: yes - I though so - that's why I guessed `if true then NEW.i=OLD.i; end if;` not just `NEW.i=OLD.i;`, O only could not guess the condition, so put `true`

Comment: It's important to check if you are trying to update a null value. If it's the case, then you should use coalesce function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39337190/6328506

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be many resons for real update  happening and yet rows values not changed: RULES, triggers, wrong schema from search_path and probably many more if you sit and think seriously. You can update other table, other row and set previous value instead of new with bothe RULES and triggers. Thus a full DDL for table and its "dependants" is needed. Here is probably the simplest example with trigger:

```
f=# create table ut(i int);
CREATE TABLE
f=# insert into ut select 1;
INSERT 0 1
f=# create or replace function tf() returns trigger as
$$
begin
if true then NEW.i=OLD.i; end if;
return NEW;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
f=# create trigger tn before update on ut for each row execute procedure tf();
CREATE TRIGGER
f=# update ut set i = 2;
UPDATE 1
f=# select * from ut;
 i
---
 1
(1 row)
```

so you see

> ```
> f=# update ut set i = 2;
> UPDATE 1
> ```

and yet data not changed.

Also after you commit changes the value could be simply updated by another transaction, thus you select value, updated after you...

Comment: This. Check your triggers with something like: SELECT * FROM  information_schema.triggers

You may be accidentally *automatically* updating your row right after you manually update it.

Answer (score 0):

Update privilege requires select as well. Maybe that was the issue or will be an issue for someone else.

> In practice, any nontrivial UPDATE command will require SELECT privilege as well, since it must reference table columns to determine which rows to update, and/or to compute new values for columns

For more info check the doc : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html